# Clone/Pull from Bare Repo

Tags: git

I have a bare GIT repo set up in my Ubuntu Server.

I have made several commits to the bare repo over several days.

When I cd to the bare repo and do a git log I get the SHA code for the several commits along with the commit messages.

How can I clone/pull the commits from the bare repo using the SHA codes so that I can get files which were committed during that commit?

Comment: `git checkout <hash>` Whats the probelm?

Comment: Thanks KingCrunch.I was trying the hash with the clone command instead of checkout.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clone the repo as usual with `git clone` and then, as you have the whole repo in your local machine, roll back to the commit you want with `git checkout HASH`.

Comment: What if I have more than one bare repo.Then how would I exclusively pull from that specific bare repo.

Comment: When you clone a repo, you have to specify the server and the route of one repo, so you will always be pulling from that repo (branches apart)

Comment: Here I have 2 bare repos.Now when I create a new non-bare repo and set the source bare repo and when I pull it works fine.Now when I checkout from a different bare repo which I have not specified the checkout command still works which should not as the source bare repo does not have that hash.But it is still working.Can you clarify.